# Order by and case in select query

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-order-by

```
users
id | status | qualified
1  | yes    | BE
2  | no     | BCOM
3  | no     | BSC
4  | no     | BE
5  | yes    | BE
```

I want users with qualified = BE to fetch first then with status yes then other users

I have written query as follows but not getting result as expected

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN qualified =  'BE'
THEN 0
 WHEN status =  'yes'
THEN 0  
ELSE 1 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL comparing results in `0` and `1`. So you can do

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
ORDER BY qualified <> 'BE',
         status <>  'yes'
```

and generally you could do

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
ORDER BY case when qualified = 'BE' then 1 else 2 end,
         case when status = 'yes' then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like

select case when qualified = 'BE' Then 1 
When status  = 'Yes' then 2 else 3 End as Ranking,
* from users order by Ranking